# Running a Service that will receive SCREEN_ON broadcast

Tags: android

I am building an app that should receive Android's `android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON` broadcast's and do something in the background.

(That broadcast is protected and can't be added to the IntentFilter section in the Manifest, it is required to be registered programmatically via `registerReceiver()`)

I know how to start a Service. I know how to make it independent of the Activity that started it (so it doesn't die with it). The real question is:

How to register the SCREEN_ON broadcast receiver in the Service, so it's received by the service even if the Service is temporarily killed by the device due to low RAM when the broadcast is sent by the system?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class OnBootService extends Service {

   private static final String TAG = OnBootService.class.getSimpleName();
   private PowerButtonReceiver mPowerButtonReceiver = null;

   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
   }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {

    if (mPowerButtonReceiver==null) {
        mPowerButtonReceiver = new PowerButtonReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mPowerButtonReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
    }
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Log.i(TAG,"onCreate()");
}

  // unregister the Receiver when the Service gets stopped (destroyed)
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    unregisterReceiver(mPowerButtonReceiver);

    Log.i(TAG, ""+TAG+" stopped: "+ new Date().toString());
   }
}
```

edit: i added the powerButtonReceiver too:

```
public class PowerButtonReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   private static final String TAG = "PowerButtonReceiver"; 

   private int mPowerClickCounter = 0;  
   private boolean inTime = true;

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

       Boolean bCheck = sharedPref.getBoolean("PowerButtonReceiverState", false);   

       // check if screen is on
       PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
       Boolean screenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
       Log.i(TAG, "Screen is on:  " + screenOn.toString());
 }}
```

Comment: is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Seems like this should do it, but what if the Service is currently being restarted (e.g. due to low memory) when the broadcast is sent by the system? Will `PowerButtonReceiver`'s `onReceive()` be still called?

Comment: the service should be active until you reboot your device or explicitly stop it. 2nd option: you can make the service sticky, then it only stop when you explicitly stop it.